# Set a different template partial for root page

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have two fluid template partials, one for the home (root) page and one for all the internal pages. Both templates use the same Backend Layout.

How do I set what template is used where?

The only info I can find ties the template to the BE layout used, but this obviously can't work when they use the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a setting for the FE Layout just above of the BE Layout in the BE.

It can be used in an `<f:if>` like so:

```
<f:if condition="{data.layout} == 1">
  <f:then>
    #partial1
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    #partial2
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

**BE Layout** is for the columns, displaying the content areas to place your content.

**FE Layout** is a different layout for the same columns and content.

Just an example of the usage of them:

With a BE Layout you can decide if you need a *Header, Main and Footer sections* in the BE or only a *Header with a Main block.*

With FE Layout you can decide if the backgroundcolor *blue* or *orange*.

Comment: I thought it was working but now it's not. I gave my home partial a name <f:section name="contentHome"> then added <f:render section="contentHome" /> in your if statement. But now the Home page does not load. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is not <f:render section> but <f:render partial=>  See here the doc: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Render.html

Comment: I used <f:render section="content" partial="example_home.html" /> to make it work. The home page shows, but now the content elements do not render on it....?

Answer (score 0):

you can have several approaches here:

1: you can create a second BE layout (as a copy of the first one) and just call this one home. You now can use this 'home' template to point to a new home template.

2: set a typoscript setting or variable and send it to your template. with a constant you can set this variable and in your fluid template you can now use an if statement to switch your templates (or partials).

Comment: Sorry, but I think that this is a wrong approach. See my answer below. He does not want to change the structure of the content but the rendering of it.

Comment: yep, was thinking of adding the front-end layout approach as a third option also. Aldo a new BE layout does not change the structure of the content if you use the same colNums.   anyhow, imo it is a matter of flavour and preference and yours is a good one.